# dynamic site security risk

Tags: php, security, dynamic, include

I heard that my website or my whole server is easy to hack because of my index.php

Here is it:

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
include_once 'includes/mysqlconnect.php';
$url_slash=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url= rtrim($url_slash, '/');
?>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Site Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $domain;?>themes/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $domain;?>themes/<?php echo $theme;?>.css">
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div class="container-all">
        <?php include_once 'includes/header.php';?>
        <div class="container">
            <?php include_once 'includes/navigationbar.php';?>
            <?php include_once 'includes/rightsidebar.php';?>
            <div class="content"><?php

            if ($url==''){

                include_once "sites/home.php";
            }
            elseif (file_exists("sites/$url.php") && is_readable("sites/$url.php")){
                include_once "sites/$url.php";

            }

            else {
                include_once 'sites/404.php';

            }


            ?></div>
            <?php include_once 'includes/footer.php';?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I prevent people from typing example.com/../../../somefilepeoplemaynotsee.txt

I would really like keeping my urls clean, so nothing about example.com?page=example
I want just to add a site by creating a file in the /var/www/html/sites/ dir and then I added a page. This is how it works not, but as said. Its a big security risk :/
I would really like keeping my site dynamic

Any ideas

Comment: You're using user-provided data (`REQUEST_URI`) to do an `include()`. That means it is POSSIBLE for someone to mangle a request to your server and include potentially ANY file on your server.

Comment: I know that. Thats the problem. Do you know how to fix it??

Answer (score -1):

Use `basename`, see: http://php.net/basename

Example:

```
$url = rtrim($url_slash, '/');
$url = basename($url);
```

(Note: this is on the *simplest* level of dynamics. Using something like MVC with known routes could be safer)

Comment: So if I added `$url = basename($url);` it would be fixed??

Comment: Can you send an example url?

Comment: Do not post links to vulnerable websites, unless you want people trying to hack your server.

Comment: No, an example url... such as example.com/foo

Answer (score -1):

In order to prevent a local file inclusion vulnerability, you must validate the user input before you try to use it as a filename for inclusion.

```
if (!preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", $url)){
    // user input is valided to A-Za-z0-9

    if(file_exists("sites/$url.php")){
        include_once "sites/$url.php";
    }
}
```

This assumes that you will only place scripts that are intended for inclusion in the `sites` directory. Obviously if you have other code there that is not to be included then you need to use a whitelist instead.

Comment: How does this protect him from someone accessing a file on any part of the system? You're saying that any file that has only `A-Za-z0-9' is safe? What about ../../../etc/passwd

Comment: That will not work. `../../etc/passwd` contains unacceptable characters that will not pass this validation.

Comment: Emm what if I would like having a url like example.com/something/some-dir/some_file Just `(!preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9---_-]/", $url))` ?

Comment: @KaareZ to achieve that I suggest splitting the user input and individually validating each directory name and finally the filename separately.